# pip install pubnub throws 'gcc' failed error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, pubnub

I am trying to install pubnub libraries and I get the error when I do pip install pubnub

```
Compiling support for Intel AES instructions
building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLTC_NO_ASM -DHAVE_CPUID_H -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o -L/usr/lib64 -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash/_MD2.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

These are the steps I followed

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python27 get-pip.py
sudo yum install git
git clone https://github.com/pubnub/python && cd python/python
sudo update-alternatives --config python
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo yum install gcc
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this, I had to follow these steps

```
ld -lpython2.7 --verbose

attempt to open /usr/x86_64-amazon-linux/lib64/libpython2.7.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-amazon-linux/lib64/libpython2.7.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libpython2.7.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libpython2.7.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libpython2.7.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libpython2.7.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-amazon-linux/lib/libpython2.7.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-amazon-linux/lib/libpython2.7.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libpython2.7.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libpython2.7.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libpython2.7.a failed
```

Check ldconfig softlink for python and find out what its pointing to

```
ldconfig -p | grep python2.7

libpython2.7.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

This shows that it was looking for a wrong softlink and I changed the soft link like this

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so
```

and then had to run pip like this

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install pubnub -- Location of pip installed
```

Worked Pretty Good

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Python's header files. How you do that will depend on your operating system.

On Debian or Ubuntu, for example, something like

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

should do it.

On Fedora / CentOS / Red Hat, try

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris . I already did install the header files. It still gives me the error. I am using AWS AMI.

Comment: @upagna, how did you install the headers?

Comment: I did sudo yum install python-devel . Updating the question of what I did until now

Comment: @upagna, what is the default Python on your machine? (Try `python --version`.) Was it installed via `yum` as well?

Comment: The default on the Machine is 2.6 and I updated it to 2.7.